# How to archive call log record in Ringcentral

Tags: ringcentral

Very new to RingCentral and exploring all the options.
Recently we have a requirement to archive call log records using c# or phython.
As per my research from the net and found that as per retention policy given here : https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/2178?language=en_US the maximum number of days the call log stays is 90 days.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement call log sync and archive this is by the call log sync API :
https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Log/syncUserCallLog
which Synchronizes call log records.
There are various API Permissions require like ReadCallLog.
You can check the official docs regarding this: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/voice/call-log/archival

More details are here on archiving the message store : https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/use-message-sync-api-to-archive-your-sms-fax-and-voicemail-messages-cd23748e188f